# Argument of type 'ApolloServer' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ApolloServerBase'

Tags: typescript, apollo-server, apollo-server-testing

I write integration tests using `apollo-server-testing` package follow this official [docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/testing/testing/). But when I pass the instance of the `ApolloServer` class to `createTestClient` method, `tsc` throw a type incompatible error.

> Argument of type 'ApolloServer' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ApolloServerBase'.
>     Types of property 'requestOptions' are incompatible.
>       Type 'Partial>' is not assignable to type 'Partial>'.
>         Types of property 'documentStore' are incompatible.
>           Type 'import("/Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/cnodejs-graphql-api-apollo/node_modules/apollo-server-caching/dist/InMemoryLRUCache").InMemoryLRUCache | undefined' is not assignable to type 'import("/Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/cnodejs-graphql-api-apollo/node_modules/apollo-server-testing/node_modules/apollo-server-caching/dist/InMemoryLRUCache").InMemoryLRUCache ...'.
>             Type 'import("/Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/cnodejs-graphql-api-apollo/node_modules/apollo-server-caching/dist/InMemoryLRUCache").InMemoryLRUCache' is not assignable to type 'import("/Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/cnodejs-graphql-api-apollo/node_modules/apollo-server-testing/node_modules/apollo-server-caching/dist/InMemoryLRUCache").InMemoryLRUCache'.

Here are the minimal reproducing code:

`topic.integration.test.ts`:

```js
import { constructTestServer } from '../../../__utils';
import { createTestClient } from 'apollo-server-testing';

describe('topic integration test suites', () => {
  it('should ', () => {
    const { server, cnodeAPI } = constructTestServer();
    const { query } = createTestClient(server); // tsc throw an error here
  });
});
```

`__util.ts`:

```js
import { ApolloServer } from 'apollo-server';
import { contextFunction as defaultContext } from '../graphql/context';
import { schema } from '../graphql/schema';
import { CnodeAPI } from '../graphql/api';

const constructTestServer = ({ context = defaultContext } = {}) => {
  const cnodeAPI = new CnodeAPI();

  const server = new ApolloServer({
    schema,
    dataSources: () => ({ cnodeAPI }),
    context,
  });

  return { server, cnodeAPI };
};

export { constructTestServer };
```

Dependencies versions:

```
"apollo-datasource-rest": "^0.6.10",
"apollo-server": "^2.9.14",
"apollo-server-express": "^2.9.14",
"apollo-server-testing": "^2.9.15",
"typescript": "^3.7.4"
```

The interface of `createTestClient` function is:

```js
import { ApolloServerBase } from 'apollo-server-core';
// ...
(server: ApolloServerBase): ApolloServerTestClient
```

So when I try to do the type assertions like this:

```
import { ApolloServerBase } from 'apollo-server-core';
// ...
createTestClient(server as ApolloServerBase);
```

`tsc` throw a new type error:

> Argument of type 'import("/Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/cnodejs-graphql-api-apollo/node_modules/apollo-server-core/dist/ApolloServer").ApolloServerBase' is not assignable to parameter of type 'import("/Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/cnodejs-graphql-api-apollo/node_modules/apollo-server-testing/node_modules/apollo-server-core/dist/ApolloServer").ApolloServerBase'.
>     Types of property 'requestOptions' are incompatible.
>       Type 'Partial>' is not assignable to type 'Partial>'.
>         Types of property 'documentStore' are incompatible.
>           Type 'import("/Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/cnodejs-graphql-api-apollo/node_modules/apollo-server-caching/dist/InMemoryLRUCache").InMemoryLRUCache | undefined' is not assignable to type 'import("/Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/cnodejs-graphql-api-apollo/node_modules/apollo-server-testing/node_modules/apollo-server-caching/dist/InMemoryLRUCache").InMemoryLRUCache ...'.
>             Type 'import("/Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/cnodejs-graphql-api-apollo/node_modules/apollo-server-caching/dist/InMemoryLRUCache").InMemoryLRUCache' is not assignable to type 'import("/Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/cnodejs-graphql-api-apollo/node_modules/apollo-server-testing/node_modules/apollo-server-caching/dist/InMemoryLRUCache").InMemoryLRUCache'.

I don't want to do type assertions like `createTestClient(server as any);`. It works, but I want to make the type correctly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think this problem caused by different versions between `apollo-server-express` and `apollo-server-testing`.
I've updated to apollo-server-express and apollo-server-testing to 2.9.16. Then, this type error has disappeared.
Please try it.

Comment: I don't know what was up with mine, but i had to remove `node_modules`, reinstall, and restart the server.